# What sequence does PuTTY send for ALT + DEL

Tags: ssh, terminal, putty, zsh, xterm

When I connect to my Debian Wheezy Beta 4 server with PuTTY 0.62 on Windows 7 I'm experiencing a problem. My login shell is Zsh and it is configured to handle <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> for the action `delete-word` (deletes one word to the right of the cursor). The line in configuration looks like this:

```
bindkey -e "\e[3;3~" kill-word
```

The binding works nicely when connected via the `ssh` command from a `gnome-terminal`. But when I connect via PuTTY this action is not executed. Instead a `[3~` is put out to the console. As far as I see it this is the unescaped sequence for the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key in `xterm`. For a while I thought PuTTY would simply ignore the <kbd>ALT</kbd> modifier and send only <kbd>DEL</kbd>, but if that would be the case, the action bound to <kbd>DEL</kbd> would have been executed as if I pressed only that key.

So I guess PuTTY is using some sequence for the key combination which I do not know and which makes to output `[3~` appear on screen. How can I find out which sequence PuTTY sends to configure Zsh to handle that correctly?

**Update**: It seems that PuTTY is supposed to ignore all <kbd>ALT</kbd> modifier keystrokes in its current implementation. Here is an excerpt from the source code file `TERMINAL.C` which deletes the <kbd>ALT</kbd> flag from the modifiers variable:

```
/*
 * Alt is only used for Alt+keypad, which isn't supported yet, so
 * ignore it.
 */
modifiers &= ~PKM_ALT;
```

That doesn't explain to me why pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> doesn't have the same effect as pressing just <kbd>DEL</kbd>. Also it doesn't explain why the default key combination for the `kill-word` action in Zsh (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick to get these sequences is to start `cat` on the remote host. That way I get `^[[3~` for <kbd>DEL</kbd> alone, but `^[^[[3~` with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>. (PuTTY 0.62 on W7/64)

So, probably

> `bindkey -e "\e\e[3~" kill-word`

will do what you want.